# What technique can I use to stop my navigation bar from flickering?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

On my webpage, I have a top menu bar not dissimilar (conceptually) to the one used at apple.com:

[image]

The issue with both my site (and Apple's) is that, when navigating between pages, the site does a full page reload and this causes a flickering of the navigation bar.

What technique can I use to ensure that the navigation bar stays entirely static when the user clicks from menu item to menu item?

Comment: Is your problem solved? If so, please select an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could cache the assets. Depending on what tech your website is already using and whether you have the flexibility, you could add more js dependencies.

Related to [Navigation bar that doesn't reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502510/navigation-bar-that-doesnt-reload)

Do you have a link to your site? The apple.com website's `navbar` seems fine to me and doesn't flicker (although some websites have a disclaimer above the navbar). Standard `Bootstrap` `navbar` also *appear* static when I navigate to each link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about your site but I think the flickering of the navigation on apple.com (actually, it's shifted to the left after the scrollbar appears) is caused by the main scrollbar. Did you try to force the main scrollbar always visible? You can take a look here [Making the main scrollbar always visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202425/making-the-main-scrollbar-always-visible)